# How to promote nodes/pages into blocks?

Tags: blocks

Standard Drupal comes with a "promote to front page" when creating new content. But I want know how to promote, let's say `News` flow to the block located to the right?

As far as I know there is no "url" for blocks so I can't really use view to assign my news flow to the blocks url. So how do I do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

I complete the previous answer about Drupal 8.

In Drupal 8 with Views (include in core) it's exactly the same way.

Add a 'Promote to block' checkbox field on your `News` content type.

Then in Views you can create a new View or you can go in the "Content" View. Then create a new "Block". Describing all Views functionalities would take a long time, but in this block you can filter all your content, particularly in the Filter Criteria sections where you can filter in order to take only News content type with only the 'Promote to block' option checked.

If needed, search for some Views tutorials. It's quite easy and very powerful.

Then call this new block instead the old one.

Comment: If you just want to use the Promote to front field, then you don't have to create another 'Promote to block' field. Then in Views, you filter on 'Promote to front'. You can do everything you want in Views

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create a block display. And within the block settings specify that you only want to show it on the "front page". The fields to be shown are probably only the title of the nodes you want to see included in that block. with that you've reduced your question (challenge) to selecting the appropriate Views "filter" and "sorting".

To filter your nodes, you could add an extra field to the content types (like your "News"?) you want to see included, whereas that field is just a boolean to yes/no indicate if it should be shown in that block.

If you'd want to make it a little more flexible (dynamic), you could also use the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module, and allow authorized users (with appropriate roles to set such flags) to flag whatever should be included in that block. Your view would then become a similar list of nodes that were "flagged".

Enough options to pick from?

PS 1: I'm assuming this question is about Drupal 7 ...

PS 2: for D8, [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) is in core ... and for [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) there is a [8.x-4.x-dev release](https://www.drupal.org/node/2409553), for which the current status is "[Under active development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2592949), but not yet ready for production."

Comment: Not suported by Drupal 8, thats one of the main reasons i asked the question :P

Comment: @Ezzor : your above comment is a crucial addition to your question, which should have been included in your original question. If you'd still add it now your question becomes a chameleon question (solution to the problem, changes the problem) ... I've updated my answer accordingly ... PS: **What** exactly is not supported by Drupal 8?

Comment: I will keep in mind to give as much background information for future questions. (Thank you for the tip)

Comment: As of now, neither of the Modules you  refereed to is cleared for Drupal 8, Views has not begun migration and Flag is in early development. As for my question if it was unclear... I want to have a news-flow inside a block which will be "updated" by making a new "content", maybe im doing it wrong, but im not sure how to do it in any other way

Comment: @Ezzor : ok, thank you for accepting my advice. But I'm still curious about the **What** it is that is not supported ... Why not extend your answer with something like "**Update**: the D7 related answer below does not work in D8 (which is what my question is about), because in D8 ...."

Comment: @Ezzor, Views now ships with Drupal 8 and is ready and safe to use.

Comment: Views is include in Drupal core since Drupal 8 ! @Pierre.Vriens give you a good way to do this on DP7, but it's totally doable on DP8.

Comment: Merci @Neograph734 (my PS 2 crossed your comment ...)

Comment: @Gaius : merci (also)! Maybe you want to post a D8 related answer? I keep being curious to find out **What** exactly is not supported in D8 ...

Comment: @All : I was assuming was that the mods Pierre was ref. to was a simplified solution to my question and i therefore jumped to the conclusion that those modules were "not included" in the core.

However, I still don't understand the solution.. So let me elaborate,

I have a Content type called "News" which I want to use for news-flow in one of my side-blocks, the problem i'm encountering is that the block it self dose not have a URL path and i can therefore not simply copy the "Promote to front page" function and change destination to the block.

Maybe I'm just being stupid and that's on me :P